Prove that there is no smooth immersion $f : M \rightarrow T^n$, where $ T^n = S^1 \times \cdots \times S^1$ is the $n$-torus.
This question is from a publicly available practice qualifying exam (Stanford geometry and topology), which I am using to help learn this field. I have seen no proof for this problem in any textbook; all work is my own.


Let $M$ be a compact, simply connected smooth manifold of dimension $n$. Prove that there is no smooth immersion $f  : M \rightarrow  T^n$, where $ T^n = S^1 \times \cdots \times S^1$ is the n-torus.

Answer: I was told from this thread to assume that the manifold is closed. A closed simply connected $n$-manifold will not immerse into $n$-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$. This is because a projection (or diffeomorphism on a projection) will lead to certain points where the differential isn't injective.
For the immersion on $M$ to be smooth, it first must be continuous. For it to be continuous, we have to immerse onto some simply connected neighborhood of $T^n$. We can form $T^{n}$ out of $T^{n-1}$ by taking a quotient $$T^{n} = {T^{n-1} \times [0, 1] \over (T^{n-1} \times \{ 1 \} ) \sim (T^{n-1} \times \{0 \})}$$ Let's now cut the space $T^{n-1} \times [0,1]$ in half. We end up with a space diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$. This is the only type of simply connected neighborhood on the torus $T^n$. Since the only possible simply connected neighborhood that we have on $T^n$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$, it follows that no immersion is possible.

(a) Is there a better way to address that the only simply connected neighborhood on $T^n$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{n}$? Is there a nicer and more rigorous way to show this then making a number of imaginary cuts?
As a bonus (not required), if you have any other proof method or lemma you want to let me know, I'd love to see it, as I come up with these proofs on my own to learn the material, and don't look for answers until I've given things a good try.

An immersion into the $n$-torus would lift to a map into the universal cover, which is $\mathbb R^n$.


once you know about the lifting to $\mathbb R^n$: an immersion (from something $n$-dimensional) is an open mapping, so its image is open, but the image is also compact


Your attempted solution is quite wrong.

@CheerfulParsnip So I can just state that since $\mathbb R^n$ is the universal cover of $T^n$, and since I can't immerse my manifold $M$ in the universal cover, the immersion fails?

Nate, more or less. You have to cite the relevant theorem that a map of a simply connected space will lift to the universal cover and argue that the lift is also an immersion.

@Nate, I made a simple proof that using the open and close. Let's look at this

An immersion in this case is a local.diffeomorphism, and is in fact a covering map.
